# 3D rotation matrix from geometric properties

Tags: matrices, rotations, parametric

> State the parameters $n_x,n_y,n_z$, then write the matrix for a rotation by $\theta=53.13^\circ$ about the axis parallel to $\mathbf n=-3\mathbf j+4\mathbf k$ passing through $P=(1.5,-1,0)$.

I'm not sure what to do with the given point P. Can I just say $n_x,n_y,n_z=0,-3,4$? I know what the rotation matrix looks like but I'm not sure if my parameters are correct.

*EDIT*: This is the rotation matrix form https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYQaK.png

Comment: It is still profoundly unclear what you intend to achieve. What are those $N_x,N_y,N_z$, where do they come from, and what should be done with them? What conversion are you talking about, when your parametric equation is _already_ Cartesian?

Comment: @IvanNeretin This is the form for the rotation matrix http://i.imgur.com/QA7mhCI.png ignore the last part sorry i'm not sure how i am meant to find the Nx Ny and Nz values from the given vector **n** and point **P**

Comment: Mathematics in general is usually case-sensitive, so beware. As for $n_x$, etc., why, just normalize your $\vec n$ and take its components.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Sorry about the confusion. So if i normalize the given vector n it becomes n= 0i + (-3/5)j + (4/5)k. Do i then use these values as my n_x, n_y and n_z? What do I do with the point P = (1.5, -1, 0)?

Comment: Yes, that's what you do. As for the point... well, subtract it before applying the rotation matrix and add after that.